# How to remove spring boot dependency using dependencyManagement?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

In my pom file i have the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I use this because the project already have a parent pom.

I want to remove some of its dependencies such as:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Than simply remove them from your pom file? Maybe I misunderstand the question?

Comment: spring-boot-dependencies adds it.

Comment: As already described it's only in dependencyManagement but not as dependency..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spring-boot-dependencies` does not add any dependency. It mostly consists out of a giant `<dependencyManagement>` block containing managed versions for several libraries. This allows you to use versions of libraries that are known to work properly with the given version of Spring boot.

That means that you no longer have to add the `<version>` to each dependency you define.

It also means that if you have a dependency  upon `elasticsearch`, it certainly doesn't come from `spring-boot-dependencies`.

If your goal is to override one of the versions, you can, by manually adding `<version>` to your dependency.

Otherwise, you can usually exclude a dependency by using `<exclusions>`:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
     <artifactId>artifact-abc</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
             <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Pretty sure spring-boot-dependencies is adding it. And <exclusin> does not seem to work with dependencyManagement.

Comment: You are right, I hade a unused dependency which was causing elasticsearch to be added. This dependency was on 6.5.4 but somehow spring version prevailed.